# Create a Mule deployable archive from a domain project using Maven

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio

When I export my domain project from Anypoint Studio using the "*Anypoint Studio Project to Mule Deployable Archive*" option, there is a checkbox saying *Export project associated with this domain*

This will generate a zip file contain the domain project as well an apps folder containing deployable versions of the associated apps. I can then take this file and deploy it to the /domain folder on the server to deploy my entire Mule solution. Is there any way to generate the same thing from Maven?

When I run *mvn clean package* against the domain project it generates a zip file in the /target folder but this is missing the apps inside.

**How can I generate the full archive using Maven?**

(I am new to Maven so may just be missing a different goal I should be specifying or maybe there is a plugin I should use?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/maven-tools-for-mule-esb) you will find documentation about how to create a Mule domain using Maven. You can also check [this GitHub project](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-esb-maven-tools) which aggregates several Maven plugins and archetypes for Mule, in particular, pay attention to the [Mule Domain archetype](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-esb-maven-tools/tree/master/archetypes/mule-domain).
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ale - I will give this a go. So does the archetype setup a build job in Maven that will generate the full zip file?

Comment: No, the archetype generates a project template for a domain project, take a look at [Maven's Introduction to Archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html). Then, the generated project builds the zip file when running maven on it.